# Where are the pull/push commands in GitHub for Windows client?

Tags: git, github, git-pull, github-for-windows

I've been using GitHub for Mac for a while and was about to help a colleague install it on Windows.

I cannot find any menu or any button to initiate "push" or "pull" as I can on Mac. Only way I see it is to open a shell and execute `git pull`.

But then, what's the point of the UI?

**What solved my problem?**

I switched to using SourceTree (http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) instead. It solved all my issues :)

Comment: Thanks I was having the same issue.  There are plenty of times when you want to pull but not push, so the sync button is mostly a terrible idea. I'm taking your advice and switching to SourceTree

Answer (score 12):

It's in the top right of the app.

For most cases you'll want to hit [the sync button](https://github.com/blog/1669-stay-in-sync-with-github-for-windows) which will [both push and pull](https://help.github.com/articles/synchronizing-repositories) for you.

You can also hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to manually trigger it.

When you have a new local branch, the **sync** button will change into **publish** ready for you to push up to remote.

[image: sync button changes to publish]

If something goes wrong it will prompt you with a need to go into shell and work things from there.

Comment: But I was asking for the "pull" command :) On the Mac client (that is vastly superior to the windows client) I can choose Repository->Pull. Is that impossible on the Windows Client or just very hidden?

Comment: Right now, impossible on the Windows client. Pull is sync, which is both push/pull

Comment: ok, so I'm basically better off using power shell if I want to pull and not push

Comment: I switched to http://www.sourcetreeapp.com for better control. It solved my problems/issues :)