# updating local copy of repository using GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I used GitHub for Windows to clone a repository(for which I am a contributor) into my local system.Now some changes have been pushed into the master copy at GitHub and I want to update my local copy with those updates using GitHub for windows. I tried to sync the repository but I guess it does only sync it with local copy but not update it as after I sync it shows 'no uncommitted changes'. how can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the pull/push commands in GitHub for Windows client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139209/where-are-the-pull-push-commands-in-github-for-windows-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'sync' option both pushes and pulls, so you've updated your copy.

The 'no uncommitted changes' message means that you haven't made any changes to this repository yourself that aren't committed.

Comment: Thanks! I got confused initially